# Jackson deserialization for php-like array concatenated with another object

Tags: java, php, hashmap, jackson, json-deserialization

Here is a bit weird json structure from external service:

```
{
   "entity_list_self_mapped_by_ids": {
     "0": { "ent_prop1": "ent0_prop_value1", "ent_prop2": "ent0_prop_value2" },
     "1": { "ent_prop1": "ent1_prop_value1", "ent_prop2": "ent1_prop_value2" },
     "2": { "ent_prop1": "ent2_prop_value1", "ent_prop2": "ent2_prop_value2" },
     "unexpected_other_property_here": {
       "foo": "bar"
     }
   },
   "one_more_not_so_important_property": { "something": "here" }
}
```

Anyway I wonder if there is any smart compact way to deserialize it to something like this

```
class ResponseContainer {
  @JsonDeserialize(converter=MapToListConverter.class)
  List<Entities> entities;
  OtherProperty unexpectedOtherProperty;
  OneMoreProperty oneMoreProperty;
}
```

MapToListConverter is quite obvious to me - just convert map values to list. Hovewer I am not sure if there is simple way to extract that 'unexpected_other_property' so it can go not to the map but to other dedicated property of ResponseContainer.

Comment: your php similar list is actually JSON array

Comment: One solution which I can imagine is a "custom deserializer" where you can try to check what `unexpected_other_property_here` represents this time. If `JSON` does not contain any property which defines type of this property you can not use any annotation or something like this.

Comment: thread here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931838/jackson-custom-property-name-to-type-mapping-for-polymorphic-properties leads me to the conclusion that there is rather no cunning solution. Some custom deserializer just need to be written to find `unexpected_other_property` and deserialize it into appropriate place.

Comment: I have found that in case the unexpectedOtherProperty is not required it is possible to use:
`@JsonIgnoreProperties("unexpected_other_property_here")` on `List<Entities> entities`. 

Next step would be to use some Dispatch/Delegate deserializer.